# Can I make a Nikon AF Nikkor 50mm 1:1.4D auto focus on a Nikon D3100?

Tags: lens, nikon, nikon-d3100, compatibility

I just got a new lens - the Nikon AF Nikkor 50mm 1:1.4D - and I'm using it on my Nikon D3100 Camera.

is there a way to get the lens to auto focus? my other lens has a switch right on the lens to change from manual to auto focus, but this one doesn't? and I'm unsure how to get it to focus. I can manually get it to focus, but I find even when things look in focus, about 50% of my pictures end up being blurry anyways!

Comment: For accurate manual focus, use the live view zoom function.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately not, as this lens does not have a built-in AF motor, and neither do the D3X00 or D5X00 camera families from Nikon. Your camera will only have autofocus with Nikon lenses marked AF-S, or compatible lenses from other makers that include built-in focusing motors.